# T-SQL : can this data be displayed using PIVOT without an aggregate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have two tables that I've been asked to create a `PIVOT` table with however there is no aggregate and after messing around with this I'm unsure this is possible.

Table A looks like:

```
ID  CustomerID  ItemCode  CustomerItemCode  CustomerItemDescription
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1          123           321              product x
2       2          123           456              product x
3       1          987           789              product y
4       2          987           567              product y
```

Table B:

```
CustomerID  CustomerName
------------------------
    1       Customer ABC   
    2       Customer XYZ
```

What the result should look like is:

```
ItemCode  CustomerItemDescription  Customer ABC  Customer XYZ
-------------------------------------------------------------
  123        product x                  321           456
  987        product y                  789           567
```

Because customers could always be added I'm trying to make this as dynamic as possible so I've gotten as far as setting up the customer columns and creating a temp table with the data but without an aggregate I'm unsure how to make this display properly.

Comment: It depends on what you know about the data. Can you have more than 2 different products?

Answer (score 1):

That is an interesting one and yes it is possible.

Here two possibilities to achieve this.

**Option 1** (the simpler to read and understand):

You can use this if you know the names of the Customers and can generate parts of the required query outside of SQL and execute the full in the end.

```
SELECT
  ItemCode,
  CustomerItemDescription,
  max(case when (CustomerName='Customer ABC') then CustomerItemCode else NULL end) as 'Customer ABC',
  max(case when (CustomerName='Customer XYZ') then CustomerItemCode else NULL end) as 'Customer XYZ'
FROM Table_A
JOIN Table_B ON Table_A.CustomerID = Table_B.CustomerID
GROUP BY ItemCode, CustomerItemDescription
ORDER BY ItemCode;
```

SQL-Fiddle for Option 1: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eEEDSao6Qy9v6um8N4zjqn/0

**Option 2** (dynamic but hard to understand):

Here you generates dynamic the query inside of the SQL using variabel and execute this in the end.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when (CustomerName = ''',
      CustomerName,
      ''') then CustomerItemCode else NULL end) as ''',
      CustomerName,''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Table_A
JOIN Table_B ON Table_A.CustomerID = Table_B.CustomerID;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ItemCode, CustomerItemDescription, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM Table_A
                  JOIN Table_B ON Table_A.CustomerID = Table_B.CustomerID
                  GROUP BY ItemCode, CustomerItemDescription
                  ORDER BY ItemCode');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

SQL-Fiddle for Option 2: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xkAaZM9Z7Wszh89PMYNYWP/0

---

Check also this article for additional infos: https://ubiq.co/database-blog/display-row-values-columns-mysql/

SQL-Fiddle for the Article: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qZedfre2FtowmsxRB5TWt8/0

Comment: Easier to understand way to form the field list and case statements would be to use a while loop. The T-SQL way to solve this is stuff an xml query, like so: ```declare @fldlist varchar(4000) = stuff((select ', '+ concat('max(case when customername = ''', CustomerName , ''' then CustomerItemCode else NULL end) [', CustomerName , ']') from Table_B for xml path('')),1,1,'')```

Answer (score 1):

Concept is right - use dynamic sql. If you are specifically working with T-SQL and SQL Server 2012+, try the following:

```
declare @fldlist varchar(max) = stuff((
       select ', '+ concat('max(case when customername = ''', CustomerName , ''' then CustomerItemCode else NULL end) [', CustomerName , ']') 
           from Table_B 
           JOIN Table_B ON Table_A.CustomerID = Table_B.CustomerID for xml path('')),1,1,'')

/*
   need to use a global temp table because dynamic sql
*/
declare @tbname varchar(255) = '##UnlikelyToBeUsedGlobalTempTblName';

/*
    there is an 8000 char limit for dynamic sql in sql server.  If there are too many customers with long names, you will need to split tables. 
*/
declare @sql varchar(8000) = CONCAT('
if object_id(''tempdb..'''+@tbname+''') is not null drop table ',@tbname,'
SELECT ItemCode, CustomerItemDescription, ', @fldlist, ' into ' , @tbname , '
                  FROM Table_A
                  JOIN Table_B ON Table_A.CustomerID = Table_B.CustomerID
                  GROUP BY ItemCode, CustomerItemDescription
                  ORDER BY ItemCode');
exec(@sql)

select * from ##UnlikelyToBeUsedGlobalTempTblName
```